# Removing chips from plastic threads

Tags: machine-elements

[image: hello! I have this thread, in the middle… and it’s a bit hard to reach with tools. Do anyone have any tips to removing them without causing any damage to the surface or the thread for that matter]

hello! I have this thread, in the middle… and it’s a bit hard to reach with tools. Do anyone have any tips to removing them without causing any damage to the surface or the thread for that matter

Comment: This particular issue is called "deburring a crosshole" and you might get better results if you search for tools meant for that. Cross holed threads are one of the more devilish things to debur though.

Answer (score 1):

This is an absolute stinker of a part. Is that threaded hole blind? If so the mold core that formed the through hole obviously had an unscrewing mechanism built into it to form a threaded blind hole in the middle of an undercut but I have to ask: The threaded hole looks as if it were there for a setscrew to engage a shaft, but how in the world would anyone turn that setscrew??

Normally the threaded hole would go completely through the part and the unscrewing mechanism would be built into the half of the mold on that side of the part, so no undercut. In this case you would clean up the threads by chasing them with a precision tap after the part cooled down from the molding process, and then blowing any chips out with an air jet.

Comment: The thread is going all the way through, it’s used as a handle for something. Idk what.

Comment: It wasn’t molded, it was made on a 5 axis mill.  and the person who made them, gave them to me so i could remove the chips from them. But i am pretty sure, you can get tools for your mill to get into these places. I just haven’t seen one yet